# How do I define equality for a generic Result<T> type?

Tags: swift, generics, equality

I have a plain `Result` type:

```
public enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case error
}
```

I want to make the type `Equatable`, easy enough:

```
public enum Result<T: Equatable>: Equatable {

    case success(T)
    case error

    // definition of ==
}
```

But then I want to use `Result<Void>`, and that’s a type error since `Void` doesn’t conform to `Equatable`. Is there a way to define a `Result` type that would conform to `Equatable`, accept `Result<Void>` and still use the correct equality check for `T: Equatable`? Wouldn’t it make sense for `Void` to implement `Equatable`?

Comment: `Void` is the type of an empty tuple, and tuples cannot conform to protocols. – When [SE-0143 Conditional conformances](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md) is implemented then you can do something like `extension Result: Equatable where T == Void`

Comment: Long discussion starting at https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20171127/041669.html

Comment: Thank you! I am impatiently waiting for conditional conformances to land, I was just hoping there’s a better solution in the meantime other than `String(describing: x) == String(describing: y)`.

Comment: Would it help that you can define a `==` operator for both `T: Equatable` and `T == Void`, without making the Result type itself conform to Equatable?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I need the Result type to feature in other type signatures with equality requirements.

Comment: You could always just define your own `struct Unit : Equatable {}` type, and use that instead of `Void`. It's a far from ideal, but I think it's probably the best you'll manage until the language can define an `Equatable` conformance for `Void`.

Comment: @Hamish: You should make that an answer.

Comment: @MartinR Hmmm, I feel like I'd end up mostly duplicating the points made in your answer, with the only addition of defining your own `Unit` type. I'm more than happy for you to add that suggestion to your answer. I can write an answer of my own if you really want though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is possible at present. `Void` is the type of the
empty tuple `()`, and tuples cannot adopt protocols (a discussion about
that topic starts at [[swift-evolution] Synthesizing Equatable, Hashable, and Comparable for tuple types](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20171127/041669.html)).

A possible workaround (as suggested by @Hamish above) is to use a custom 
type instead of `Void`:

```
struct Unit: Equatable {
    static var unit = Unit()
    public static func ==(lhs: Unit, rhs: Unit) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

let res = Result.success(Unit.unit)
```

---

I initially though that once [SE-0143 Conditional conformances](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md) is implemented then one could define

```
public enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case error
}

public extension Result: Equatable where T: Equatable {
    public static func ==(lhs: Result, rhs: Result) -> Bool {
        // ...
    }
}

public extension Result: Equatable where T == Void {
    public static func ==(lhs: Result, rhs: Result) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

without the need the make `Void` itself `Equatable`.

However (again attribution goes to @Hamish) this won't work 
because multiple conformances won't be permitted.

Comment: Conditional conformances will unofficially be a part of Swift 4.1 (they'll be a compiler option that's disabled by default; although the stdlib will be built with it enabled). Though hopefully they will be officially part of the next version (maybe 4.2?). Although unfortunately, multiple conformances won't be permitted (i.e you can't conditionally conform to the same protocol more than once, even if the constraints are clearly disjoint), so you won't be able to conform to `Equatable` for both `T: Equatable` & `T == Void`.